# change a click event dynamically to dojo button

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I am trying to set a on click event dynamically. After i read some data and get back true, onclick event need to do one thing on dijit/form/Button and when i get back false onclick event need to do other thing on same button.

```
if(m_test==true){
        if(dojo.byId(tmp_tst_button)){
            dojo.removeClass(tmp_tst_button,'button_fr');
            dojo.addClass(tmp_tst_button,'button_fr_toggle');

            var change_on_click = dojo.byId(tmp_tst_button);
            dojo.connect(change_on_click,'onclick',function(){
                command(tmp_binary_off);

            });
        }            
    }
    else{
        if(dojo.byId(tmp_tst_button)){
            dojo.removeClass(tmp_tst_button,'button_fr_toggle');
            dojo.addClass(tmp_tst_button,'button_fr');

            var change_off_click = dojo.byId(tmp_tst_button);
            dojo.connect(change_off_click,'onclick',function(){
                command(tmp_binary_on);

            });

        }            
    }
```

and event is connect, but every time data is changed one more event onclick is ADD, so when i click on button i call multiple times command and more and more every next time. Like command functions is appended to button every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your dojo.connect code as below.

```
var handle = dojo.connect(change_on_click,'onclick',function(){
                command(tmp_binary_off);
                // disconnect after use.
                dojo.disconnect(handle);

             });
```